# How to get all 3D and 2D delivertives after uploading linked revit files by Forge API?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I had upload linked revit files to BIM360Docs.

And, I wanna download all 3D and 2D delivertives.

I had request `GET :urn/manifest` API.

But, result was empty.

How to get informations about all delivertives?

Thank you!

[image: 3D]

[image: 2D]

Answer (score 0):

The viewables of a file are **not exposed** on the `manifest` endpoint, only other derivatives (e.g. IFC, OBJ), but you can download it as described on these blog posts: [Nodejs](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-svf-extractor-nodejs), [.NET](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-svf-extractor-c-net) & [PHP](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/php-sample-extract-svf).

**EDIT**

`urn` is the unique identifier for model translated, if you uploaded to a bucket, you can list objects on it, and the JSON response will include the `urn`. If the model is on BIM 360, then it's on the [GET version](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-versions-version_id-GET/) response.

Answer (score 0):

@augusto-goncalves 
Thank you for reply.

For single model,  I am using this and successfully download all delivertives.
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-svf-extractor-nodejs

But for linked revit file, I am wondering.
This program needs derivativeUrn.
How can I get derivativeUrn?

`// URN of model to download
const urn = 'dXGhsujdj .... '`

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this answer (StackOverflow didn't notify me...), see my edit below